# How to split hours worked into 3 custom groupings taking into account shifts that go past midnight

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do some data crunching. I'm trying to split hours worked into 3 catagories, pre 11am, 11-7pm and post 7pm. Unfortuantly I don't have much experience at all with VBA so enlisted the help of ChatGPT and it almost worked. However if a shift spans past midnight it ends up returning a negative number in the Pre 11am.

Using ChatGTP it gave me this code:

```
Function SplitHours(startTime As Date, endTime As Date) As Variant
    Dim pre11am As Double
    Dim elevenToSeven As Double
    Dim post7pm As Double
    
    ' Check if start and end times are valid dates
    If Not IsDate(startTime) Or Not IsDate(endTime) Then
        SplitHours = "Invalid input: Start and end times must be valid dates."
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Check if the end time is greater than the start time
    If endTime <= startTime Then
        SplitHours = "Invalid input: End time must be greater than start time."
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Calculate hours for each category
    Dim startHour As Double
    Dim endHour As Double
    
    startHour = Hour(startTime) + Minute(startTime) / 60
    endHour = Hour(endTime) + Minute(endTime) / 60
    
    If endHour <= 11 Then
        pre11am = endHour - startHour
    ElseIf startHour >= 19 Then
        post7pm = endHour - startHour
    Else
        If startHour < 11 Then
            pre11am = 11 - startHour
        End If
        If endHour > 19 Then
            post7pm = endHour - 19
        End If
        elevenToSeven = WorksheetFunction.Max(WorksheetFunction.Min(endHour, 19) - WorksheetFunction.Max(startHour, 11), 0)
    End If
    
    ' Return the results as an array
    SplitHours = Array(pre11am, elevenToSeven, post7pm)
End Function
```

I'm not sure how to fix it so if a shift goes past midnight it applies to the post 7pm group.

Comment: Incease endHour by 24 times the day difference `endHour = Hour(endTime) + Minute(endTime) / 60 + 24 * (Int(endTime) - Int(startTime))`

Comment: You my friend get a gold star! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

As commented by User CDP1802:
Incease endHour by 24 times the day difference

```
endHour = Hour(endTime) + Minute(endTime) / 60 + 24 * (Int(endTime) - Int(startTime))
```

I have added this to my VBA script and it works great!